# Linear relation between three infinite matrices, the first two are symmetric and the third is a matrix of ones plus a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, symmetric-matrices

For $n\geq 1$, let $G_n$ be the matrix $G_n=(g(i,j))_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ where
$g(i,j)=\max(i,j)$ if $i\neq j$ and $0$ otherwise.

If we define
$$A_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, B_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, H_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Then we have the identities $G_2A_2=2H_2$ and $G_2B_2=2I_2$. Next, if we consider

$$
A_3=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{10}{9} \end{pmatrix}, B_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & \frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}, H_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & \frac{4}{3} \\ 1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3} \\ 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}\tag{2}
$$

Then we have $G_3A_3=I_3+3H_3$ and $G_3B_3=5I_3+3H_3$. Continuing in this vein, if we put

$$
A_4=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{7}{12} \\
0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{7}{12} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{10}{9} & \frac{7}{9} \\ \frac{7}{12} & \frac{7}{12} & \frac{7}{9} & \frac{113}{72} \end{pmatrix}, B_4=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{5}{4} \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{4} \\ 1 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{5}{3} \\
 \frac{5}{4} & \frac{5}{4} & \frac{5}{3} & \frac{43}{24}\end{pmatrix}, H_4=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{11}{6} \\ 1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{11}{6} \\ 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{11}{6} \\  1 & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{5}{6} \end{pmatrix}\tag{3}
$$

then $G_4A_4=\frac{10}{3}I_4+\frac{16}{3}H_4$ and $G_4B_4=10I_4+8H_4$.

We can now formulate the following **conjecture** : there are three infinite matrices $A_{\infty}=(a(i,j))_{i,j\in {\mathbb N}}$, $B_{\infty}=(b(i,j))_{i,j\in {\mathbb N}}$ and $H_{\infty}=(h(i,j))_{i,j\in {\mathbb N}}$, such that if we denote by $A_n,B_n,H_n$ respectively the upper-left corner submatrices of those matrices (so that $A_n=(a(i,j))_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$, and so on), then

1. $A_{\infty}$ and $B_{\infty}$ are symmetric (i.e. $a(i,j)=a(j,i),\  b(i,j)=b(j,i)$ )
2. $h(i,j)=h(j,j)+1$ when $i\neq j$
3. $A_2,B_2$ and $H_2$ are given by \eqref{1} above,
4. For every $n$, one has constants $a_n,b_n$ such that $G_nA_n=a_nI_n+(a_n+2)H_n$, $G_nB_n=b_nI_n+(b_n-2)H_n$.

Any ideas on how to prove that conjecture (or find a counterexample) ?

Here are a few possibly useful data for small values :

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
a_n & 0 & 1 & \frac{10}{3} & \frac{91}{12} & \frac{73}{5}  & \frac{9199}{360}   & \frac{13232}{315} &  \frac{147879}{2240}  & \frac{129929}{1296} \\
\hline
b_n & 2 & 5 & 10 & \frac{73}{4} & \frac{175}{5}  & \frac{6197}{120}   & \frac{1228}{15} &  \frac{40273}{320}  & \frac{81427}{432} \\
\hline
h(n,n) & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{6} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{85}{36}  & \frac{871}{252}   & \frac{1083}{224} &  \frac{118939}{18144}  \\
\hline
\end{array}
\tag{4}
$$

Other things I noticed :

4. All the entries of $A_{\infty},B_{\infty}$ and $H_{\infty}$ seem to be positive rationals, except for the zeroes from $A_2,B_2,H_2$.
5. If we exclude the upper-left $2\times 2$ square, the first two rows of $A_n$ are identical ; same property for $B_n$.

Comment: I think there is a typo for your (2,3) and (3,2) entry for matrix $A_4$. Or your first conjecture fails

Comment: @MilosTasic Corrected, thanks

Comment: Have you considered putting $C_n:=A_n+B_n$ and $c_n:=a_n+b_n$ and seeing if you can prove $G_n C_n=c_n[I_n+H_n]$? I haven't chased through much of it but the entries and constants seem more structured to me. It would be a start ...

Comment: @ancientmathematician Looks promising, I'll give it a try, thanks